# Access Windows password-protected files in python

Tags: php, python, powershell, password-protection

I'm trying to access a user/password protected file on a remote windows machine in python. How do I do this? It seems like an easy problem but I've been googling around for a while, to no avail.

**Details:**

I have an IIS web server running from a Windows 8 computer. I want to have a button that calls a script that goes into some password-protected files on this computer. So when the button is pressed, I have the following php, which calls python on ActiveChannelScraper.py in the scripts folder, and echoes all the shell data to the browser:

```
$runCMD = 'C:\Anaconda\python scripts\ActiveChannelScraper.py';
$output= shell_exec($runCMD . "2>&1");
echo( '<pre>' );
echo( $output );
echo( '</pre>' );
```

All the test print statements are printing, up until the line `os.listdir(p)`, at which the program clearly stops running because I don't get any print statements after that. Which makes sense, because it can't list the files in p, because p is password protected.

I've done `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser` in Powershell on the machine with the server.

In my Python script, I tried net use:

`os.system("net use /user:" + USER + " " + p + " " + PASS)`

But it gives me the error message

```
System error 86 has occurred.

The specified network password is not correct.
```

I tried it on my own computer with my own username and password and it gave me `The command completed successfully.` I double-checked the username and password, they're definitely right.

Comment: What file types have had passwords applied? Password protection is added by an application not Windows. Perhaps you mean that you need to get access to a different user profile on the other machine?

Comment: This is a windows file share password lock.

Answer (score 0):

System Error 86: if You are sure the password is correct that mean You typed username without domain. It should be /user:remotecomputername\Username or /user:remoteIPaddress\Username if You don't have a domain.
And don't use 'p' letter before password:

*net use \\192.168.0.2 mysecretpassword /USER:192.168.0.2\Username*